# FlinkCEP: Can I reference an earlier event to define a subsequent match?

Tags: scala, flink-cep

Here is a simple example:

```
val pattern = 
   Pattern.begin[Event]("start").where(_.getId == 42).
   next("middle").subtype(classOf[SubEvent]).where(x => x.getVolume == **first event matched**.getVolume) ...
```

Essentially the second event ("middle") need to access the state of the first event ("start"). Is it possible to do this within FlinkCEP without requiring an external state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can get events by for a specific pattern with the help of Context.

```
new IterativeCondition<Event>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 8061969839441121955L;

            @Override
            public boolean filter(Event value, IterativeCondition.Context<Event> ctx) throws Exception {
                double sum = 0.0;
                for (Event e : ctx.getEventsForPattern("middle")) {
                    sum += e.getPrice();
                }
                return sum > 5.0;
            }
        }
```