# Apache Flink CEP pattern detection with java

Tags: java, apache-flink, complex-event-processing

I want to do;
to start with CEP with any of the arraylist elements included in the map structure and to continue with the rest of the arraylist elements I have started.
map and pattern structure:

```
final Map< Integer,ArrayList<String>> deger = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>>();
        deger.put(1,new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("h:1","l:1","g:0")));
        deger.put(2,new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("h:1","l:1","g:1")));
        deger.put(3,new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("h:2","l:3","g:1")));
        deger.put(4,new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("h:0","l:2","g:2")));

 for(int i=1;i<deger.size()+1;i++) {
            temp1.add(deger.get(i));
        }

Pattern<String,?> pattern = Pattern.<String>begin("start").where(
                new SimpleCondition<String>() {
//                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(String value) throws Exception {

                        for (ArrayList<String> aa: temp1){
                            for (String dd : aa)
                                if(value.equals(dd)){ 
                                    return true;
                                }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
        ).followedBy("middle").where(
                new SimpleCondition<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(String value) throws Exception {
                        return value.equals(temp1.get(1));
                    }
                }
        ).followedBy("end").where(
                new SimpleCondition<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(String value) throws Exception {
                        return value.equals(temp1.get(2));
                    }
                }
        );
```

my aim is to give warning with arraylist elements in the map but the order of the arraylist elements is not important because of the stream stream therein.I want to proceed with the remaining elements of this array where I can return the information of this array when I start with any array here. For example:

```
Incoming data = "l:1","h:1","g:0"
my pattern = "h:1","l:1","g:0" 
Start -> l:1 find
Middle -> g:0 or h:1 | h:1 find
End -> g:0 find -> alarm
```

Comment: Hey, what exactly is `temp1` here ?

Comment: CEP is based on the time series to some extent. Why not just use a loop to find the elements if you don't care the time?

Comment: I've added temp1 it right above the pattern function

Comment: I work real time so time is important

Comment: Okay, so just to clarify. You want to raise an alarm, if there is any pattern from the list in any possible order, *but all elements must belong to the same list*?
So You would like to raise an alarm if `"h:1","l:1","g:0"` come in any order but if "h:1","l:1","g:2" then it will be no alarm here ?

Comment: should not be. an alarm must be generated for each list. so "h:1","l:1","g:2" no alarm. I want to use the key in map to find out which list of alarms is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static  Integer temp1;
    public static  Map<Integer,ArrayList<String>> temp2 = new HashMap<>();     
final Map< Integer,ArrayList<String>> deger = new HashMap<>();
            deger.put(1,new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("h:1","g:1","s:0")));
            deger.put(2,new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("h:1","g:1","g:0")));
            deger.put(3,new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("h:1","c:0","g:0")));
            deger.put(4,new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("h:1","s:1","g:0")));


            Pattern<String,?> pattern = Pattern.<String>begin("start").where(
                    new SimpleCondition<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean filter(String value) throws Exception {
                            flag = false;
                            for(Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entryStart : deger.entrySet()) {
                                if(entryStart.getValue().contains(value) && !temp2.containsKey(entryStart.getKey())){
                                        ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
                                        newList.addAll(entryStart.getValue());
                                        newList.remove(value);
                                        temp2.put(entryStart.getKey(),newList);
                                        flag = true;
                                }
                            }
                            return flag;
                        }
                    }
            ).followedBy("middle").where(
                    new SimpleCondition<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean filter(String middle) throws Exception {
                            flag = false;
                            for(Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entryMiddle : temp2.entrySet()) {
                                if(entryMiddle.getValue().contains(middle) && entryMiddle.getValue().size() == 2){
                                    ArrayList<String> newListMiddle = new ArrayList<String>();
                                    newListMiddle.addAll(entryMiddle.getValue());
                                    newListMiddle.remove(middle);
                                    temp2.put(entryMiddle.getKey(),newListMiddle);
                                    flag = true;
                                }
                            }
                            return flag;
                        }
                    }
            ).followedBy("end").where(
                    new SimpleCondition<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean filter(String end) throws Exception {
                            flag = false;
                            for(Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entryEnd : temp2.entrySet()) {
                                if(entryEnd.getValue().contains(end) && entryEnd.getValue().size() == 1){
                                    flag = true;
                                    temp1 = entryEnd.getKey();
                                }
                            }
                            if (flag)
                                temp2.remove(temp1);
                            return flag;
                        }
                    }
            );

            PatternStream<String> patternStream = CEP.pattern(stream_itemset_ham,pattern);

            DataStream<String> result = patternStream.select(
                    new PatternSelectFunction<String, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String select(Map<String, List<String>> map) throws Exception {
                            ArrayList<String> NewList= new ArrayList<>();
                            NewList.addAll(deger.get(temp1));
                            String found = "Found";
                            for (String list_element : NewList)
                                found += " " + list_element ;
                            return found;
                        }
                    }
            );
            result.print();
```

I understand from your question that this kind of solution can be offered.

Comment: This solution will basically match every combination of the elements of all patterns, no matter if it is really a pattern or not. I mean, if You will have the following input stream `"h:1",  "d:1", "g:1" , "b:9" , "s:0", "z:0", "g:0"` it will still find two patterns: `h:1 g:1 g:0` and `h:1 g:1 s:0`, but there are no patterns in the input.

Comment: Hi dominic, Actually, you're right about that also  It's important to find patern in my code but it's not important to find a element.
Can you share me if you have a solution in a different way?

Comment: Hey, l have added an answer :)

Comment: **IterativeCondition** didn't know it was such a thing. I have learned. Thank you Dominik.

Answer (score 1):

so currently AFAIK Flink does not support not ordered patterns out-of-the-box, so basically I see two ways of tackling this issue:

1) You could create all possible patterns that you want to search for and simply union all resulting data streams.

2) As this post suggests [FlinkCEP: Can I reference an earlier event to define a subsequent match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55309321/flinkcep-can-i-reference-an-earlier-event-to-define-a-subsequent-match) You can try to use `IterativeCondition` that will allow You to access previous elements that were already matched, so basically You would have to define pattern that matches all possible elements from the lists and then simply check in the last condition if all three of them belong to the same list. If so the pattern is found.